# open sublime text with git bash

Tags: javascript, git-bash, sublimetext4

I tried to open sublime with git bash but I get error :

[image]

and this is the

[image]

I tried many solutions over the internet, and I can't find the answer, I'm on windows and my sublime version 4143

Comment: Image 1, you're looking in the folder "Sublime Text 3", image 2, you're looking in the folder "Sublime Text" (no '3')

Comment: Is `subl` a custom alias that you made?

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes